# Java appears to be outdated when using java -jar command

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

I have recently been writing some Java programs on my Windows computer. I have been trying to use `java -jar` to run compiled jars in order to see errors more clearly, but when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/company/app/GUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

This obviously means that my java version is outdated. However, when I took a look at the Java Updater, it shows that I am running the latest version.
Running `java -version` shows this:

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

So why is Command Prompt using an older version, and how do I change it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: what does `java -version` say?

Comment: Java updater in the system tray should not be (and it is not) your local binaries of Java platform. Try to see what you have in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: `which java` will tell you where the `java` binary is being called from

Comment: I have tried running `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `which java`, neither of which returned what I expected (%JAVA_HOME% and "'which' is not recognised..." respectively)

Comment: @nullTerminator+ on Windows it's `where` not `which`. But it almost certainly won't find the actual installed JRE; Sun/Oracle Java installers for Windows have long used either (progdata)\something\java\javapath or (progfiles[x86])\something\java\javapath for a stub launcher that uses the registry to find the real jvm.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error clearly indicates that you try to run a `.jar` file built with JDK 13 (major version 57) on a JRE/JDK 8 (major version 52) which is provided in `PATH` setting and thus invoked when running `java -jar` / `java -version` commands.

If you have JDK 13 installed on your machine, you need to check environment variable `PATH` and/or `JAVA_HOME`:

```
C:\Users\hp1>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java\jdk-13.0.2

C:\Users\hp1>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin

C:\Users\hp1>java -version
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If `PATH` refers JRE/JDK 8, you may create another variable and update `PATH` (copy non-java paths):

```
>set JAVA_13=**path_to_your_jdk_13**
>set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;%JAVA_13%\bin
```

If you do not have JDK 13 on your machine, to resolve this issue you should rebuild the `.jar` file to make it compatible with JDK 8 providing that the code is not using any features from the newer versions.

Comment: I know what this means, that isn't my question. I want to change Command Prompt to use JDK 13.

Comment: Do you have JDK 13 on your machine?

Comment: To clarify. The application you are trying to run is built on JDK 13. Your machine is running Java 8. You will likely need to download and install [JDK13](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk13-downloads.html) and specify your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Yes, that's how I complied the jar in the first place

Comment: You could have compiled jar using some IDE (eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans) which can be installed with their own JDK

Comment: @AlexRudenko I am using NetBeans, which if I remember correctly needs Java to be pre-installed

Comment: @professionalgrammer, have you been able to modify `PATH` environment variable on your system to provide path to the directory where JDK 13 is installed?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I reset the PATH variable and modified the Java section. `java -version` now shows 13.0.2.